# Marker Title is not displaying on GoogleMapView in iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, google-maps, gmsmapview

Hello all I am using GoogleMaps to display multiple markers on mapview. Maps is working fine and it display multiple markers according to coordinate. but it it not displaying the title of the location.

I am using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:cityLattitude
                                                            longitude:cityLongitude
                                                                 zoom:7];
    [self.mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
    //GMSMapView *mapView; //= [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

    [mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

    mapView.indoorEnabled = NO;
    mapView.mapType = kGMSTypeNormal;
    viewFormap = mapView;
    mapView.accessibilityElementsHidden = NO;
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    NSLog(@"User's location: %@", mapView.myLocation);

    mapView.delegate = self;

    GMSMarker * marker = [[GMSMarker alloc]init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(cityLattitude, cityLattitude );
    marker.map = mapView;
    [mapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];

}
```

To display annotations i used the following code:

-(void)plotMutliplePinsOnMap//:(NSArray *)MapDataArray
{
for(int i=0;i<[MapDataArray count];i++)
{

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 20)];
// Set label properties as required including marker Name

UIImageView *markerIconImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(35, 10, 30, 50)];
// Set image properties as required including image which will be displayed as marker

UIView *markerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[markerView addSubview:label];
[markerView addSubview:markerIconImageView];


//GMSMapView *mapView = [[GMSMapView alloc]init];
viewFormap = mapView;
latitude = [[[MapDataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
longitude = [[[MapDataArray objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];

eventTypeStr = [[MapDataArray objectAtIndex:i]objectForKey:@"is_paid"];

NSString * price = [[MapDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"evt_price"];
NSString * Mainprice = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",price];

NSString * name = [[MapDataArray objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"evt_title"];
NSLog(@"Name is %@", name);

for(int i=0;i<[MapDataArray count];i++){
    GMSMarker * marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    if ([eventTypeStr isEqualToString:@"0"])
    {
    NSLog(@"Eventtype Array is %@",eventTypeStr);
    NSLog(@"Event Type is %@",eventTypeStr);
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"smiley.png"];

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
    marker.title = name;
    marker.snippet = name;
    marker.tappable = YES;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    //marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
    [mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
    }
    else if ([eventTypeStr isEqualToString:@"1"])
    {
    NSLog(@"Event Type is %@",eventTypeStr);
    //marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"dollar1.png"];
    marker.icon = [self drawText:price inImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"markertt1.png"]];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
    marker.title = price;
    marker.snippet = name;
    marker.tappable = YES;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    //marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
    [mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
    }
    else if ([eventTypeStr isEqualToString:@"2"])
    {
    NSLog(@"Event Type is %@",eventTypeStr);
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"donation.png"];

    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude,longitude);
    marker.title = name;
    marker.snippet = name;
    marker.tappable = YES;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    //marker.animated = YES;
    marker.map = mapView;
    [mapView setSelectedMarker:marker];
}
}
```

}
}